# hiding the autocomplete list when user click outside the textbox is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to show the autocomplete list when user types some character in the text box. I have 3 text boxes with autocomplete feature. I was trying to hide the autocomplete list when user click on somewhere else outside the textbox or press the esc button from the keyboard.Example, when user types some character (A) in the textbox it shows the autocomplete list from where the user can select the text, but if user doesn't want to select any text from autocomplete and click somewhere outside the textbox or esc button it should hide/remove the autocomplete list which is failing with my code.

Demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/0qynmbgjob7rp94PUaIR?p=preview

The below code is not working as expected:

```
  #country1:not(:focus) + .list-group {
    display: none;  
}
#country2:not(:focus) + .list-group {
    display: none;  
}
#country3:not(:focus) + .list-group {
    display: none;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML doesn't have `country1` element in it. So, change `country1` to `country` in your css:

```
#country: not(: focus) + .list - group {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Oh i have not noticed, i modified the country1 to country but still not working as expected..Please find the demo http://plnkr.co/edit/rYxkU6Uxlk6k985shUvt?p=preview . It is not allowing to select the element from the autocomplete list.